# Create a floating point number from a vector of digits after the decimal point

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a vector `A` in Matlab of dimension `Nx1` containing natural numbers, e.g.

```
N=8
A=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]
```

I want to transform `A` into an array `B`

```
B=[0.12345678]
```

where `0.12345678` is a double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array from `10^-1` to `10^(-numel(A))` and perform element-wise multiplication with the transpose of `A` (to make it `1 x N`) and then sum the result

```
result = sum(A.' .* 10.^-(1:numel(A)));
fprintf('%0.8f', result)
%   0.12345678
```

To actually demonstrate how this works, we can demonstrate with a smaller `A` vector.

```
A = [1; 2; 3; 4];

tmp = 10.^-(1:numel(A));
%  0.1000   0.0100   0.0010   0.0001

tmp = A.' .* tmp;
%  0.1000   0.0200   0.0030   0.0004

result = sum(tmp);
%  0.1234
```

An alternate way to think about this would be to divide `A` element-wise with `10^1` to `10^(numel(A))`

```
result = sum(A.' ./ 10.^(1:numel(A)));
```

Another alternative is to convert your digits to strings using ASCII codes and then prepend `'0.'` to the beginning of the string and then convert this to a double using `str2double`

```
result = str2double(['0.' A.' + '0']);
```

Comment: May I ask you how many digits after the comma is Matlab actually considering? E.g. Suppose `N=200`

Comment: Is there any rule on how far from the comma Matlab goes?

Comment: @user3285148 You are limited by the floating point representation so `N = 200` isn't going to work. You'll need to use variable precision arithmetic or strings to represent numbers with that precision